# SVN to GIT gone wrong?

Tags: git, git-extensions

I'm tring to convert my svn repo to a git one to do this I did the following :

1/create a authors.txt file
2/use this commande :

```
git svn clone [SVN repo URL] --no-metadata -A authors-transform.txt --stdlayout ~/temp
```

It all went well but now my git repo look like this in git extension :

[image: the repo]

How can I delete the bre/trunk and trunk green thingy?
I'd also like to delete the bre/cloud1 ans cloud1.

Unfortunatly the contextual option "delete this branch" won't show.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following steps recently to convert a svn repo to git

```
mkdir my_project_svn
cd my_project_svn
git svn init http://svn.blah.com/blah/trunk/ --no-metadata
git config svn.authorsfile ../authors.txt 
git svn fetch
```

And everything worked like a charm. You can read more about the process [here](http://nathanhoad.net/how-to-migrate-your-svn-repository-to-git)

Comment: worked like a charm, I just added "git remote rm origin" to remove the origin

Comment: ohh yh... forgot to mention that... I found that part of the tip somewhere else ;)